# difference between reading the /proc/stat files via syscall fucntion read () or via glibc function fread()

Tags: linux, fread, procfs, lseek, procstat

Program reading /proc/stat files  via read(like cat) or via fread (like nl) return different values. read() /proc/stat return right result, while fread() return wrong result.

I had write simple C programs that just read or fread /proc/stat. read() return right values, like `cat /proc/stat`. fread() return wrong values,like `nl /proc/stat`.

I execut "top" command in my Centos7 system and then press "1" to show every cpu's detail information, it only show cpu0's information, while my system have 8 cpu cores. further more, the cpu0's information is wrong.

So I read the source code of top command, found out that it user fread() to get cpu info from /proc/stat.I change the file reading interface from glibc fread() function to read(), and it works well.

I use fread() to retrieve other file in /proc,like /proc/meminfo, it works well too.

1. fread() to get info from /proc/stat（command 'nl' use fread() to read content in a file）

```
[root@pro_app_server workspace]# nl /proc/stat
     1  cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
     2  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
     3  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     4  ctxt 543672
     5  btime 1544675938
     6  processes 2774
     7  procs_running 4
     8  procs_blocked 0
     9  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    10  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    11  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    12  ctxt 543672
    13  btime 1544675938
    14  processes 2774
    15  procs_running 4
    16  procs_blocked 0
    17  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    18  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    19  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    20  ctxt 543672
    21  btime 1544675938
    22  processes 2774
    23  procs_running 4
    24  procs_blocked 0
    25  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    26  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    27  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    28  ctxt 543672
    29  btime 1544675938
    30  processes 2774
    31  procs_running 4
    32  procs_blocked 0
    33  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    34  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    35  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    36  ctxt 543672
    37  btime 1544675938
    38  processes 2774
    39  procs_running 4
    40  procs_blocked 0
    41  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    42  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    43  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    44  ctxt 543672
    45  btime 1544675938
    46  processes 2774
    47  procs_running 4
    48  procs_blocked 0
    49  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    50  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    51  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    52  ctxt 543672
    53  btime 1544675938
    54  processes 2774
    55  procs_running 4
    56  procs_blocked 0
    57  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    58  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    59  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    60  ctxt 543672
    61  btime 1544675938
    62  processes 2774
    63  procs_running 4
    64  procs_blocked 0
    65  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    66  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    67  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    68  ctxt 543672
    69  btime 1544675938
    70  processes 2774
    71  procs_running 4
    72  procs_blocked 0
    73  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    74  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    75  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    76  ctxt 543672
    77  btime 1544675938
    78  processes 2774
    79  procs_running 4
    80  procs_blocked 0
    81  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    82  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    83  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    84  ctxt 543672
    85  btime 1544675938
    86  processes 2774
    87  procs_running 4
    88  procs_blocked 0
    89  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    90  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    91  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    92  ctxt 543672
    93  btime 1544675938
    94  processes 2774
    95  procs_running 4
    96  procs_blocked 0
    97  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
    98  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
    99  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   100  ctxt 543672
   101  btime 1544675938
   102  processes 2774
   103  procs_running 4
   104  procs_blocked 0
   105  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
   106  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
   107  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   108  ctxt 543672
   109  btime 1544675938
   110  processes 2774
   111  procs_running 4
   112  procs_blocked 0
   113  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
   114  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
   115  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   116  ctxt 543672
   117  btime 1544675938
   118  processes 2774
   119  procs_running 4
   120  procs_blocked 0
   121  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0 0
   122  cpu0 0 0 1699 249246 71 0 6 0 0 0
   123  intr 0 28 0 0 0 378 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 4129 0 124 1 0 1251 0 3 0 6879 6680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   124  ctxt 543672
   125  btime 1544675938
   126  processes 2774
   127  procs_running 4
   128  procs_blocked 0
   129  softirq 188202 0 129718 1 457 0 0 1 35688 0 22337
[root@pro_app_server workspace]#
```

2. read() to get info from /proc/stat（command 'cat' use read() to read content in a file）

```
[root@pro_app_server workspace]# cat -n /proc/stat
     1  cpu  2058017 66 399693 188962556 16705 0 18516 5046 0 0
     2  cpu0 192984 3 47418 23679955 1327 0 3599 658 0 0
     3  cpu1 360654 16 59590 23478307 3861 0 2961 850 0 0
     4  cpu2 322760 24 53901 23533358 3234 0 2684 736 0 0
     5  cpu3 271322 4 52696 23600674 2217 0 2168 660 0 0
     6  cpu4 246241 13 48638 23643590 1678 0 1918 557 0 0
     7  cpu5 236649 2 46872 23660881 1362 0 1772 553 0 0
     8  cpu6 208005 2 45099 23691054 1219 0 1718 484 0 0
     9  cpu7 219399 1 45476 23674734 1804 0 1694 545 0 0
    10  intr 731124153 637 15753 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 34 44262 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 74547 0 0 358100 16030715 243 0 24 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    11  ctxt 698139400
    12  btime 1559549547
    13  processes 1436019
    14  procs_running 2
    15  procs_blocked 0
    16  softirq 240304636 1 96899354 179 55128202 0 0 6370 22706849 0 65563681
[root@pro_app_server workspace]#
```

3. user read() and fread() to retrieve other file under /proc, it seems normal
4. My C program with read()

```
[root@pro_app_server workspace]# cat readstat.c -n
     1  #include <stdio.h>
     2  #include <stdlib.h>
     3  #include <sys/types.h>
     4  #include <sys/stat.h>
     5  #include <fcntl.h>
     6
     7  #define BUF_INC_SIZE 1024
     8
     9  int main()
    10  {
    11          int fd = 0;
    12          FILE *file = NULL;
    13          char *buf =NULL;
    14          size_t buf_size = 0, tot_read = 0, sgl_read = 0;
    15
    16          fd = open("/proc/stat", O_RDONLY);
    17          if(fd < 0)
    18                  perror("read /proc/stat fail!");
    19
    20          buf = malloc(BUF_INC_SIZE);
    21          if(!buf)
    22                  perror("malloc fail!");
    23          buf_size += BUF_INC_SIZE;
    24
    25          while(-1 != (sgl_read = read(fd, buf + tot_read, buf_size - tot_read)))
    26          {
    27                  tot_read += sgl_read;
    28                  if(tot_read < buf_size)
    29                          break;
    30
    31                  buf = realloc(buf, (buf_size += BUF_INC_SIZE));
    32          }
    33
    34          free(buf);
    35          close(fd);
    36          return 0;
    37  }
[root@pro_app_server workspace]#
```

5. My C program with fread()

```
[root@pro_app_server workspace]# cat freadstat.c -n
     1  #include <stdio.h>
     2  #include <stdlib.h>
     3
     4  #define BUF_INC_SIZE 1024
     5
     6  int main()
     7  {
     8          FILE *file = NULL;
     9          char *buf =NULL;
    10          size_t buf_size = 0, tot_read = 0, sgl_read = 0;
    11
    12          file = fopen("/proc/stat", "r+");
    13          if(!file)
    14                  perror("read /proc/stat fail!");
    15
    16          buf = malloc(BUF_INC_SIZE);
    17          if(!buf)
    18                  perror("malloc fail!");
    19
    20          buf_size += BUF_INC_SIZE;
    21
    22          while(0 < (sgl_read = fread(buf + tot_read, 1, buf_size - tot_read, file)))
    23          {
    24                  tot_read += sgl_read;
    25                  if(tot_read < buf_size)
    26                          break;
    27
    28                  buf = realloc(buf, (buf_size += BUF_INC_SIZE));
    29          }
    30
    31          free(buf);
    32          fclose(file);
    33          return 0;
    34  }
[root@pro_app_server workspace]#
```

As the adviser of  aschepler, I strace my C program. :

6、strace info of read() /proc/stat  (part of result):

```
[root@pro_app_server workspace]# strace ./readstat
execve("./readstat", ["./readstat"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xcfb000
.
.
.
.
open("/proc/stat", O_RDONLY)            = 3
read(3, "cpu  2275345 66 527271 203616681"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "..., 1024) = 602
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
[root@pro_app_server workspace]#
```

7、strace info of fread() /proc/stat    (part of result)

```
[root@pro_app_server workspace]# strace ./freadstat
execve("./freadstat", ["./freadstat"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xdeb000
.
.
.
open("/tmp/tmpfeQoAKy", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
unlink("/tmp/tmpfeQoAKy")               = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
open("/proc/stat", O_RDONLY)            = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7692850000
read(4, "cpu  2277177 66 528841 203745262"..., 1024) = 1024
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f769284f000
write(3, "cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0"..., 4096) = 4096
write(3, " 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "..., 1024) = 602
write(3, " 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"..., 4096) = 4096
write(3, " 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7692850000, 4096)            = 0
write(3, "5938\nprocesses 2774\nprocs_runnin"..., 1200) = 1200
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "cpu  0 0 3375 498153 97 0 10 0 0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, " 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, " 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, " 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "5938\nprocesses 2774\nprocs_runnin"..., 4096) = 1200
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f769284f000, 4096)            = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
[root@pro_app_server workspace]#
```

Comment: But the implementation of `fread` probably calls `read`. To narrow this down, I'd write simple C programs that just `read` or `fread` that file, to eliminate other differences from `cat` and `nl`. Output from `strace` might reveal something interesting too.

Comment: I had write simple C programs that just read or fread  /proc/stat.                    
read() return right values, like `cat /proc/stat`. fread() return wrong values,like `nl /proc/stat`.

Comment: Show that C program.

Comment: I added The C program  to my question.

Comment: Great work on investigation. I believe fread() doesn't work due to mmap/lseek usage. These virtual files in procfs don't support these operations.

Comment: is this related to different implementations of the two?  I don't see any difference, other than `nl` printing line numbers

Comment: But I seems that fread() work well in other /proc/* files(except /proc/stat) in my test system.

Comment: these message in strace fopen() is wired:
'''
open("/tmp/tmpfeQoAKy", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
        write(3, ....)
        read(3,....)
```

the message write to & read from /tmp/tmpfeQoAKy（which fd is 3） seems like the error output.

Comment: Problem is showed. Because my server was Infected by a virus "/usr/local/lib/libioset.so",it was wrote in /etc/ld.so.preload. it will hijack some system call,like ```fstat（）```.